# Particles not showing up in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I know that this is a common issue from the questions already asked around, but I've checked every setting and I am at my wit's end. The particles are supposed to be there, but I have looked through every render setting and they will not show, if I do a quick render or a full render.

Here's the download link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eq9jg9npgjpiqjy/AAAXSED5dfQLWs99Mve86NxQa?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

The object named "fountain particle water" (a sphere) has its ray visibility disabled for camera rays, so enable that, as shown in the image below, and the problem should be gone.

[image]