# Two Particle Systems - Fire +Water, But only one shows - How come?

Tags: particles

I am working on a project to shoot out fire and want to have it start as liquid then go to flame. I couldn't figure that out so I decided to have two particle systems, one for each material.

I can get the flames to show, but can't see the liquid particles, no matter what I try. I have a dupli object, materials applied etc, but only the fire shows in the view port and render.

How can I get the other material, set to a diffuse black for now bc I was worried that the glass/water effect was hiding it.

[image: two particle systems]

Here's the blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, stupid me!

On further exploration and clicking on everything I could find, I opened the object properties tab/Cycles settings.

Ray Visibility for Camera was unchecked for some reason. I don't remember clicking it but obviously I must have.

I found it through @tacofisher answer here: [Particles not showing up in cycles render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/particles-not-showing-up-in-cycles-render)

Check it on and suddenly the particles show up[image: ![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXnyZ.jpg)